# Convertir dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss a to_date("dd/MM/yyyy", 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

Tags: c#, sql, plsql, foxpro

Tengo un Datetime en una bd FoxPro, la cual quiero migrar a Oracle DB, pero el campo FechaHora no logro parsear al formato correcto,

El dato es: 02/10/2020 9:49:16

Lo hago de la siguiente manera, pero no lo acepta el script del oracle

```
DateTime.Parse(dr["FECHAHORA"].ToString().Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

alguna alternativa para ello?

Comment: Por favor añade el error que estás recibiendo. Saludos.

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: No recuerdo que exista en SQL de Oracle o PL/SQL de Oracle una función "DateTime.Parse", puede ampliar la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

si te es de ayuda te puedo decir lo siguiente:
Me ha pasado lo mismo, pero al tratar de migrar los datos a un servidor SQL Server.
Realicé una consulta para ver el formato de fecha y hora que tenía configurado el servidor sql

```
select GETDATE()
```

y Como Resultado Obtuve `2021-10-12 12:53:28.213`

Entonces llegué a la conclusión de realizar el formateo de fecha y hora así:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")
```

Ojalá te pueda ayudar!

Answer (score 0):

En las bases de datos Oracle existe el tipo de dato DATE que:

Almacenado internamente en 7 bytes,
NO tiene formato alguno,
Consta de 2 componentes:

- un componente de fecha: año (de 4 dígitos), mes (de 1 a 12), día  (de
  1 a 28, 29, 30 o 31 según el mes que corresponda)
- y un componente
  de tiempo: horas (de 0 a    23), minutos (de 0 a 59), segundos (de 0
  a 59) y se guarda internamente en 7 bytes

Cuando se hace una consulta (SELECT) a una tabla lo que se "ve" en una pantalla o se escribe en reporte de una columna o un variable de tipo DATE lo que se hace es aplicar un formateo de ese valor que puede ser:

- automático según sea la configuración regional (NLS) del cliente SQL con el
  cual se hace la consulta o
- explícito cuando se usa la función de  conversión "to_char" que permite convertir un valor de tipo DATE a un string aplicando algún formato a discreción del programador:

  to_char(miFecha,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')